# Equivalent for IDbSet<T> in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework, fluent-nhibernate

Hey there, I've started to play around with Fluent NHibernate and now I want to could do something like `IDbSet<T>` like I could in EF Code First.. However I cant find any equivalent interface?

Thanks in adavance!

Comment: NHibernate doesn't need that. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to declare something like a DbSet<T> where all the entities for T is and then use that DbSet to .Add, .Remove, .Select etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NHibernate you operate with entities through the `ISession` interface ([reference docs with example](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#quickstart-playingwithcats)). You may wrap the session in a repository if you want (example: [Sharp Architecture repository](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture/blob/master/src/SharpArch/SharpArch.Data/NHibernate/NHibernateRepository.cs))

Comment: There isnt some kind of collection I can use to pass from method to method and then return it to the method with the ISession and save it?

Comment: With IDbSet<T> could I do something like: IDbSet<Person> = context.Set<T>(); where context was DbContext.. Can I do something similar in fluent nhibernate?

Comment: @ebb: use the Repository pattern. See the link I posted.

Comment: @RJB that is not unusual after three years, but you could always look up archive.org or something like that and edit the answer.